# Помогите пожалуйста, нужно перевернуть число

Tags: ассемблер

```
_asm
    {
        mov k, 32
        xor ecx, ecx
    m1:
        mov eax, x
        mov s, 0
        mov ebx, 1
        cmp ecx, k
        je ex1
    v1:
        cmp s, ecx
        je vex1
        shl ebx, 1
        inc s
        jmp v1
    vex1:
//      shl ebx, ecx
        and eax, ebx
        cmp eax, 1
        jnz a1
        mov edx, 32
        sub edx, ecx
        dec edx
        mov s, 0
        mov eax, 1
    v2 :
        cmp s, edx
        je vex2
        shl eax, 1
        inc s
        jmp v2
    vex2 :
//      shl 1, 32 - ecx - 1 
        or z, eax
    a1:
        inc ecx
        jmp m1
    ex1:
    }
```

// Необходимо перевернуть число x со всеми его нулями. Получить число в z.

Comment: А что значит "перевернуть число x со всеми его нулями" ? Стоит пример показать. Что такое z (k,s)?

Comment: int k, s, z = 0; стоит перед этим.

Comment: А насчёт переворота?

Comment: Перевернуть все 32 бита числа, (последний должен стать первым, первый последним и т. д.) .

Comment: Приведённый код этого не делает? Потрудитесь задать качественный вопрос.

Comment: при х = 1 работает правильно, а в остальных случаях нет

Answer (score 0):

Если без изысков и оптимизаций:

```
var
  u: DWord;
begin
  u := $80050001;

  asm
    push ebx
    mov edx, u
    mov eax, edx
    mov ecx, 31
  @@cycle:
    shl eax, 1
    shr edx, 1
    mov ebx, edx
    and ebx, 1
    or eax, ebx
    loop @@cycle
    mov u, eax
    pop ebx
  end;

  memo1.lines.Add(u.ToHexString); //  8000A001

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mov eax, X
mov ecx, 32
@@: shr eax, 1
rcl Z, 1
loop @b
```